# Computer hangs when resuming from sleep

Tags: linux, fedora, sleep, power-management, fedora-17

My laptop (HP Pavilion g7-1075dx Fedora 17 64-bit) does not resume after I put it to sleep, about every third time. I can put it to sleep and wake it up two times or so, and the next time I try it, the screen stays black, but the power button **does** stop blinking (as though it was waking up). Then I try to restart it by holding the power button till it turns off, and then pressing the power button, but the screen still stays black. No BIOS POST, or anything. The way I can get the computer to turn on is to unplug it, remove the battery, put the battery back in, and then it starts up fine.

Does anyone have *any* ideas at all about why it does not resume from sleep every time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long standing problem that is not being addressed.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=788433

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=862475

Comment: It's not bug 78843... checking 862475.

Comment: It's not bug 862475 either.

Comment: When I reboot, I don't even get a BIOS POST, which the linux kernel has nothing to do with.